# Suddenly "pyinstaller -F " doesn't build my python program anymore

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Suddenly "pyinstaller -F "  doesn't build my python program anymore.

Here is the build output... then it suddenly ends back to the DOS prompt.  Nothing is built in the "dist"  folder:

```
C:\Users\rferrari\PycharmProjects\PerfMonitor>pyinstaller --clean -F PerfMonitor.py

249 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7

249 INFO: Python: 3.9.2


249 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
249 INFO: wrote C:\Users\rferrari\PycharmProjects\PerfMonitor\PerfMonitor.spec

249 INFO: UPX is not available.

249 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\Users\rferrari\AppData\Local\pyinstaller

249 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\rferrari\\PycharmProjects\\PerfMonitor']

687 INFO: checking Analysis

687 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent

687 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...

687 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...

702 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...

3061 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.

3061 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Python39\\lib'

5873 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...

6092 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc

6092 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Python39\python.exe

6170 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\rferrari\PycharmProjects\PerfMonitor\PerfMonitor.py

7326 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.

7326 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'

11700 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.

14949 INFO: Processing module hooks...

14949 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

14949 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

14949 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

14949 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

15136 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

15136 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

15340 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

16417 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    backend Gtk3Agg requires cairo

16980 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed

17511 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK4Agg": ignored
    backend Gtk4Agg requires cairo

18105 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed

18636 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)

19182 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
    No module named 'IPython'

19745 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "QtAgg": ignored
    Failed to import any qt binding

20307 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "QtCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed

20838 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": ignored
    Failed to import any qt binding

21479 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed

22619 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added

23744 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed

24634 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added

25712 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    No module named 'wx'

26243 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'

26790 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'

27462 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added

28087 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed

29477 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added

30727 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added

31586 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added

32273 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added

33351 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added

35647 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36225 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36225 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36319 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'

36350 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36350 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36350 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36350 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36772 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36772 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36788 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

36788 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

37397 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.

37866 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!

37912 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!

37912 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

38850 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

38850 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

39225 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

39225 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

39225 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...

39225 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend using `auto-py-to-exe`.
You can install it by typing `pip install auto-py-exe` in the console.
Then go to any console that you have and type: `auto-py-to-exe` and do
all the stuff.

Comment: Tried that tool, exact same result...
I have been using "pyinstaller --onefile" (and without --onefile) for the last year with both Python37 and Python 39.
But thank you.